# How to reuse signed cookies set by Play Framework 2.2 in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, authentication, playframework-2.0

**Background:**
My company has a REST-api developed in Play Framework 2.2 and we use Play's built in authentication using signed cookies as security. Our application is split up into multiple instances of Play all sharing the same application.secret. This enables us to read the session cookie on all instances of Play very easy.

**Problem:**
Right now we're in the process of migrating some parts of the REST-api to Node.js and would like to use the same session cookie there (with same application.secret) to detect if a user is logged in or not. I've searched the internet and I haven't found anything on the topic.

**Question:**
So, is it possible to do it? Is it considered secure enough or do I need to migrate to another method of authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie is encoded in CookieBaker:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala#L430

with an HMAC-SHA1 signature using Crypto.sign:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/Crypto.scala#L98

You have the application secret and presumably Node.js has the same signature algorithm, so you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to solve it with the Crypto module in Node.js by using the following line of code. This will generate the signature given the data part of the cookie. The data part must be parsed first though.

`crypto.createHmac('sha1', "APPLICATION_SECRET").update("DATA_PART_OF_COOKIE").digest('hex')`